# The reason for the width difference between Javascript and React

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently converted JavaScript code to React. Despite no changes in HTML and CSS, as evident in the pictures, the width of the `<nav>` tag differs, causing the second button to be cut off from the screen. The development tool shows the width of  as 1476 in JavaScript, but it's 1920 in React. Why does this width difference occur when they have the same CSS, particularly the same width settings?

JS 
[image: JS]

REACT 
[image]

**Javascript**

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-5" id="page1">
        <nav>
          <img src="../asset/Screenshot.png" alt="Screenshot" />
          <div id="right-nav">
            <button>Book a Demo</button>
            <button>
              <i class="ri-menu-line"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <video
          src="https://thisismagma.com/wp-content/themes/magma/assets/home/hero/1.mp4?2"
          autoplay
          loop
          muted
        ></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
style.css

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: a;
  src: url(../asset/jost-variable.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: b;
  src: url(../asset/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: c;
  src: url(../asset/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.ttf);
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1137ca;
}

#page1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
#page1 > video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
#page1 > nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#page1 > nav > img {
  margin-top: -1.7vw;
  width: 9%;
}
#right-nav > button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #0b48ed;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: a;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.bottom-page1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  height: 35vh;
  width: 50vw;
  left: 10%;
}
.bottom-page1 > h1 {
  font-family: a;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
.bottom-page1-inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: 35%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bottom-page1-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: a;
}
.bottom-page1-inner > button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0b48ed;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: b;
}
.bottom-page1-inner > h4 {
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
}
```

**React**

```
App.jsx

import React from "react";
import { GlobalStyle, Wrap } from "./styles";
import "remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Wrap>
        <div id="main">
          <div id="page1">
            <nav>
              <img src="../asset/Screenshot.png" alt="Screenshot" />
              <div id="right-nav">
                <button>Book a Demo</button>
                <button>
                  <i className="ri-menu-line"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <video
              src="https://thisismagma.com/wp-content/themes/magma/assets/home/hero/1.mp4?2"
              autoPlay
              loop
              muted
            ></video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Wrap>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
styles.jsx

  import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

  export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
  `;

  export const Wrap = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    #main {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #1137ca;

      #page1 {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: relative;

        nav {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: space-between;
          position: absolute;
          height: 10vh;
          width: 100vw;
          padding: 0px 30px;

          img {
            margin-top: -1.7vw;
            width: 9%;
          }

          #right-nav {
            button {
              padding: 10px 20px;
              border-radius: 50px;
              background-color: #0b48ed;
              border: 1px solid #fff;
              color: #fff;
              font-family: a;
              font-size: 15px;
            }
          }
        }

        video {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
      }
    }
  `;
```

Comment: App is wrapped by document, so maybe the css is wrong there, just do an inspect element and find the root cause!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I didn't understand the point well. Can I have more details?

Comment: put both the html and react websites in two different browser windows, then  open inspect element on both of them, then check the css for each of them and the html tags should be the same, you will find the culprit css or html tag, then you can fix it!

Comment: Of course, I've already checked and found out that the width of the <nav> tag is different, although they have the same CSS. I want to know why this difference occurs 

Comment: @DgUZH yes, but the width of an element is influenced not only by its own styles. And as far as I can tell, you've lost the first 10-15 lines from your `style.css` in your react app

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your seperate code examples in action, though my intuition would be to examine if the `box-sizing: border-box;` property is inherited by the `nav` element as it now looks like the padding is added to the `100vw` width.